# Can a ClickOnce deployed app be silently mass installed?

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, clickonce, setup-project, deployment-project

I have a smart client app (WinForms/WPF) currently deployed using ClickOnce.

A particular client has expressed the desire to silently deploy the app to it's intranet network users as part of its nightly/weekly client PC update service - presumably via MS Systems Management Server (SMS) and Group Policy or similar (I don't understand the exact mechanisms). As such, they've requested a .MSI installer instead.

So a few questions for confirmation (along with my thoughts on answer - am more than happy to be wrong!):

- Can a ClickOnce app be silently installed en-mass by admin???

  - *My thoughts:* No, because ClickOnce is a per-user installation this would be difficult unless the user is actually logged in at time of remote installation.
- Is there a tool to convert a ClickOnce app/project's settings to a simple MSI installer project (e.g. Visual Studio Deployment Project)???

  - *My thoughts:* Not in the box, but would **love** a tool to repeatedly copy/use settings from the ClickOnce config to the deployment project - e.g. ProductName, *Version*, *File Associations* etc. This way we only maintain one set of deployment settings.

Any other alternatives for this scenario to get 'er done quick...?

Comment: Just a thought, couldn't you create an MSI to deploy only the shortcut? Creating an MSI for the app would beat the purpose of ClickOnce (automatic update etc.)

Comment: @Krumelur - Good idea. Will propose it. Ha! A bootstrapper to the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can install a ClickOnce application silently, certainly not with SMS. And I don't know of any tool that does that, but it doesn't mean it doesn't exist. ;-)

The idea of deploying a shortcut is an interesting thought. Have you ever noticed that if you leave a shortcut on the desktop even after the application is uninstalled, if the user clicks on it, it reinstalls the application?